# Windows keyboard logging. A trait of the WM_CHAR message in various applications

Tags: c++, windows, hook, keyboard-hook

Good day. There was a need to monitor typed text, ie No keystrokes, but namely derived characters.

At the beginning I use the raw input method for obtain a virtual key codes of pressed keys, but this decision had to be abandoned because failed to properly convert virtual key codes to characters.

MapVirtualKeyEx + LoadKeyboardLayout - did not give the desired effect, ie if the load the Russian layout by calling LoadKeyboardLayout, then MapVirtualKeyEx still returns to Latin A for code 0x41.

So I began to use the hook WM_GETMESSAGE.

```
if (nCode < 0)
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);

// WH_GETMESSAGE
if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
{
    PMSG pMsg = (PMSG)lParam;
    if (pMsg != NULL)
    {
        if ((pMsg->message == WM_CHAR)||(pMsg->message == WM_UNICHAR))
        {
            keyEntry.character = pMsg->wParam;
            ipc->SendData(&keyEntry, sizeof(CHARENTRY));
        };
    };
};

return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
```

Everything works fine, including for the characters with Dead key.

But when I tried to type the text in the editor of a visual studio, problems occured:

- For one key press comes two identical messages WM_CHAR;
- For the Cyrillic characters the value WM_CHAR-> wParam does not match the characters typed, for Latin - all right.

How to convert virtual key code to a character considering input language of the process in which the text is typed + able to recruit composite characters (for example: ô). Or tell me how to solve the problems in the version with hooks.

Thanks in advance )

Answer (score 1):

A keyboard generates two scan codes when the user types a key — one when the user presses the key and another when the user releases the key.

Source : About Keyboard Input - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx

WM_CHAR will only be UTF-16 if the application is compiled for Unicode as
the character encoding (i.e. the difference between MBCS and UNICODE). If
your application is built with MBCS (multi-byte character set), then the
system will use the current system code page to convert the Unicode
character to "Ansi" (in quotes) and send that.

So check in your build settings for which character encoding your app is
configured for.

Source : Unicode and Multibyte Character Set (MBCS) Support  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey142t48(v=vs.80).aspx